# Kubernates CoreDNS direct a public url to a internal server

Tags: kubernetes

I have an app running in Kubernetes clusters which is accessing to a public API URL for e.g. `api.server123.com`. The app is accessing it within its code itself

I want to resolve that public UZRL to an internal IP like how we can do it in `/etc/host` i.e. an entry like `1.2.3.4    api.server123.com` where that IP belongs to one of our internal servers. This is for me to see the payload sent out and some internal checks.

Can I do this via the CoreDNS?

I did it like this but does not seems to work.

```
Corefile: |-
    .:53 {
        errors
        health
        kubernetes cluster.local. in-addr.arpa ip6.arpa {
            pods insecure
            upstream
            fallthrough in-addr.arpa ip6.arpa
        }
        hosts {
            1.2.3.4     api.server123.com
            fallthrough
        }
        prometheus :9153
        forward . /etc/resolv.conf
        cache 30
        reload
        loadbalance
    }
```

Is this the correct way to resolve a public URL to an internal IP within Kubernetes?

Answer (score 0):

I recommend you to use **forward plugin** for Corefile configuration.
According to [Kubernetes.io](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/administer-cluster/dns-custom-nameservers/#coredns-configmap-options):

> forward: Any queries that are not within the cluster domain of Kubernetes will be forwarded to predefined resolvers (/etc/resolv.conf).

Useful examples you can find at [coredns.io](https://coredns.io/plugins/forward/#examples)

Comment: Hello @Ruster and welcome to ServerFault! Please remember to [react to answers for your questions](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers). 
That way we know if the answers were helpful and other community members could also benefit from them. Try to [accept answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer) that is the final solution for your issue, upvote answers that are helpful and comment on those which could be improved or require additional attention. Enjoy your stay!